# ASP.NET MVC WebForms Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-mvc-routing

As i know we can use MapRoute and MapPageRoute for routing in asp.net mvc. I'm using MapRoute for routing but it's not working that well. If i remove first route then second is working well, i hope to use both of them. Am i trying to do impossible? or just missing the puzzle?

**My Global.asax File:**

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
        name: "first",
        url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { lang= "en", controller = "", action = "" }
        );

routes.MapRoute(
        name: "category",
        url: "{lang}/{category}/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { lang= "en", menu="", controller = "", action = "", category="" }
        );
```

**in *.aspx file**:

```
NavigateUrl="<%$RouteUrl:controller=consulting, action=cars, category=service%>"
```

**My Output of URL:** en/consulting/cars?category=service 
**Expected Output:**  en/service/consulting/cars

**Do you have any idea?**

Comment: Because your `NavigateUrl` matches the first route and stops search any other routes. Swap the order.

Comment: Okay, i have another question then. We have route: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}" but we have different aspx or ascx pages. how can i add {pagename} to route with NavigateUrl="", different pages located in different folder.

Answer (score 0):

***I create a solution but i am not sure if it's a best way:***

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("default", "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/", "~/Views/{controller}/{action}.aspx", true,
        new RouteValueDictionary { { "lang", "en" }, { "controller", "default" }, { "action", UrlParameter.Optional } });

        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("services", "{lang}/services/{controller}/{action}/", "~/Views/services/{controller}/{action}.aspx", true,
        new RouteValueDictionary { { "lang", "en" }, { "controller", "consulting" }, { "action", "cars" }});
```

Second URL will be not working automatically with NavigateUrl="" *but you know the **path** now*. So, it should be work:

**NavigateUrl=** "~/en/services/consulting/cars"

**Result:** http://yourwebsite.com/en/services/consulting/cars